# Select id that is related to two different values of another column

Tags: sql, database

Given these 3 tables:

```
dishes(id, name)
ingredient(id, name)
recipes(id_dish, id_ingredient)
```

I want to know the name of dishes that have both ingredient A and ingredient B in their recipe.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT name FROM dishes
JOIN recipes
  ON dishes.id=recipes.id_dish
JOIN ingredient
  ON recipes.id_ingredient=ingredient.id
WHERE ingredient.name ="A"
```

If the request was to find the dishes that have either ingredient A or B I could just add an OR ingredients.name="B" in the last line, but in this case I can't add an AND ingredients.name="B" because the same ingredient can't have two differents name.

How can I differentiate the two different ingredients in this situation to make the correct query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT d.name
FROM dishes d JOIN
     recipes r
     ON d.id = r.id_dish JOIN
     ingredient i
     ON r.id_ingredient = i.id
WHERE i.name IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY d.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) = 2;
```

Note the use of table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thanks! Is this the only solution or could there also be a way to differentiate the ingredients in the where clause?

Comment: @Mizzet . . . I'm not quite sure what you mean.  This does differentiate the ingredients in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You are right, I didn't fully understand one thing about the solution but now is all clear!